# eclipse java can not find xml file

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

i am currently having a problem regarding an xml file while programming in eclipse android.
the problem is that it seems to ask for a folder called R within my project but such a folder was not created on creation of the project.

i have had a look on the internet and review other questions but i cant quite seems to find a solution.

i am trying to set an xml file for a list and this is all the code that should be needed but it can not find the .xml file at all as it seems to want a folder called R to contain it.

```
new ArrayAdapter<Object>(this,R.layout.edit_item_layout , theList);
```

anyhelp and suggestion will be well received

UPDATE of useful information

The weird part is it can find activity_main.xml which is in the same folder

the file is located in res/layout

ok i cleaned and now it is giving a list of files i can change it to but the file itself doesn't seem to be in the R.java file ad it is asking me to change it to different files but not the one i want

Comment: Just put your edit_item_layout.xml into the `/res/layout` folder. The R class should then automatically get generated.

Comment: Is the xml in /res/xml or /res/layout?

Comment: It is located in the layout folder that is why i am confused i see no R files either

Answer (score 0):

`R` refers your `res` folder. You should have a subfolder in `res` called `layout` that contains your `edit_item_layout.xml`.

If you're receiving the error `R cannot be resolved to a variable`, you'll need to:

```
import your_package_name.R;
```

If you're receiving the error `edit_item_layout cannot be resolved or is not a field`, try:

- Cleaning your project by selecting: **Project** --> **Clean**
- Right clicking your project and selecting: **Refresh**

If you're `R.java` file is corrupted, because it's automatically generated you can also delete your `gen` folder and it should be replaced immediately.

Comment: it is asking me to create it as a field instead of finding it.

Comment: @user258030 It sounds like your layout isn't being automatically added to your `R.java` file. Try cleaning your project or some of the other suggestions I mention.

Comment: ok i cleaned and now it is giving a list of files i can change it to but the file itself doesn't seem to be in the r.java file. i also tried removing the gen folder but that didn't fix it it seems it cant find it in R.java

Answer (score 0):

R is automatically generated, and you should never add or delete from this file.

I have faced this problem many times, and it mostly caused by xml file.

```
You should check your XML file carefully. It is most likely that you will find your answer there.
```

If your importing any library, make sure you're importing those file correctly.